# Sprite-Kit colorizeWithColor not blending the sprite with the correct color

Tags: ios, objective-c, colors, sprite-kit

I have a sprite (healthbar) in my scene and I wish to colorize it whenever the player gets hit. I can colorize my sprite with greenColor, and blueColor. However, redColor, brownColor, yellowColor, cyanColor, and whiteColor all don't seem to work.

**Sprite:**

[image] _healthBar

**Code:**

```
SKAction *pulseRed = [SKAction sequence:@[
[SKAction colorizeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] colorBlendFactor:1.0 duration:0.15],
[SKAction waitForDuration:0.1],
[SKAction colorizeWithColorBlendFactor:0.0 duration:0.15]]];

SKAction *repeat   = [SKAction repeatActionForever:pulseRed];

[_healthBar runAction: repeat];
```

**Output:**

[image] [SKColor redColor] Not Working

**Other Colors:**

[image] [SKColor yellowColor] Not Working

[image] [SKColor blueColor] Working

[image] [SKColor greenColor] Working

The yellow seems to make sense, since yellow and blue make green. However, I don't think this is what's happening here.

Any thoughts?

---

**EDIT:**

There is a workaround, which other people have hinted at below, that works great with rectangular sprites (basically create a colored sprite on top of your textured one). However, I would like to find a solution that not just for rectangular sprites, since I will be using this strategy to colorize other sprites in my game.

**Solution for colorizing a rectangular sprite (Ahmet Cevdet):**

@interface

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKSpriteNode  *filterNode;
```

@implementation

```
CGSize filterSize = CGSizeMake(_healthBar.size.width, _healthBar.size.height);
SKColor *filterColor = [SKColor redColor];

_filterNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:filterColor size:filterSize];
_filterNode.alpha = 0;
[_healthBar addChild:_filterNode];

SKAction *fadeIn = [SKAction fadeAlphaTo:.6 duration:.15];
SKAction *fadeOut = [SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0 duration:.15];
SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.1];

[_filterNode runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[fadeIn,wait,fadeOut]]] withKey:@"pulseRed"];
```

Comment: I encountered something like this with an `[SKColor whiteColor]` flash to make it flash white. It did literally nothing. I think what it does is add or subtract the specific colour from the sprite, or something like that. I can't explain exactly but the way I solved it was by adding a sprite of the same size with the desired colour and placing it over the top of the health bar and then fading the alpha in and out. A bit of a dodgy workaround but it worked.

Comment: @Andy, you're right. If I change my sprite to a white bar, it works just fine. This bizarre effect only happens when the sprite is colored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code that all you need, I wish it helps;

```
@implementation MyScene
{
    float filterParameter;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {

    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];

        SKSpriteNode *healthBar = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"health"];
        healthBar.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);

        SKEffectNode *effectNode = [SKEffectNode node];
        [effectNode addChild:healthBar];
        [self addChild:effectNode];

        filterParameter = 0;

        CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIHueAdjust"];
        [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:filterParameter] forKey:@"inputAngle"];
        effectNode.filter = filter;
        effectNode.shouldEnableEffects = YES;

        SKAction *wait =[SKAction waitForDuration:0.1];
        SKAction *block = [SKAction runBlock:^{
            filterParameter += 0.1;
            [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:filterParameter] forKey:@"inputAngle"];
            NSLog(@"%f", filterParameter);
        }];

        [effectNode runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[block, wait]]]];

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: This is a great workaround. However, it would only work with rectangular sprites (which in my case it does). In the future, I would like to tint irregular sprites (enemies and bosses) whenever they get damage.

Comment: thanks dude, for u I edited the code in a way that exactly u want, hope this time it helps :)

Comment: Ahmet, colorizing the healthbar sprite does not work here either :( This is essentially the same code as my original example (albeit you used blocks and colorWith instead). Same results though. 

You should leave your original answer though, since that did work.

Comment: hmmm I will try a new method now, and let you know

Comment: Jonny I edited the post, this time u got what u need :) hope to see a smile on your face

Comment: Wow... This seems like overkill, but it works! I had to modify my code a little bit because healthBar was already a child of an SKCropNode (to make it a progress bar). I had to make SKEffectNode the parent in order for this to work. Anyway, I'm sad that colorizing doesn't work! is this a documented bug?

Comment: I am also shocked that why colorizing doesn't work, y I hope they fix that problem soon with new sprite kit improvements